# Приватный репозитарий jenkins

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

Прицепляю к дженкинсу приватную репку. Не получается. Пишет это:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- git@github.com:Flesspro/grader-v2-deploy.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Я сделал: добавил ключ в гит. Добавил креды в дженкинс. Всё равно. Что ещё может быть? Использую плагин `git over ssh`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был перепутан ключ локальной машины с ключом от дженкинса. Решение: пересоздать все необходимые ключи заново, с нуля. Тогда будут исключены все неочевидные ошибки. Данные рецепт носит общий характер.